# Is Varnish Cache blocking .conf file rules? (ex: redirection between webpages)

Tags: .htaccess, nginx, server, configuration, configuration-files

Configuration:

- Serveur: Nginx
- Langage development: C++
- Cache: Varnish

Today, we can't have any .htaccess file because we are working with C++.

Knowing that .htaccess isn't recommended. I asked if we could use .conf / virtual host file.

But apparently some developpers told me that the fact that our website has Varnish cache, we can't use .conf because of "layers of caching that bypass .conf files".

I am not an expert in all of that, I am learning but... why would cache bypass .conf redirection ?

We need to find a way to make redirection rules on a lot of pages and I haven't find a way to do that without the .conf file yet...

Thank you!

Comment: Varnish is usually sitting between your clients and nginx, so it is the first point the request will reach, but still it should not prevent you from doing the desired redirects...

Comment: Yes, because it is still the server that send the cache... And same for logs? Even if there is Varnish, there is still two kind of logs navigator and backend? Cache does not prevent to have the logs? Thank you very much. I have trouble understanding this barrier between the backend cache and the server...